# Redirect from http to https

Tags: iptables, http, redirect, https

I have a Hudson/Jenkins installation which runs on port 443, so I can access it with `https://ci.mydomain.com`.
I do not have a webserver running on port 80 like Apache Httpd, but I want if a user types `http://ci.mydomain.com` 
it should be redirected to `https://...`

I tried it with `iptables`:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 443
/sbin/iptables-save
chkconfig --level 35 iptables on
```

But the browser tells me, that the connection failed. So I do not want to install Apache webserver, I only 
want to have a redirect from `http://ci.mydomain.com` to `https://ci.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Okay I have to install sth. like Apache. And then, what is the best way to redirect?

Answer (score 10):

iptables **IS NOT** what you want here -- You are sending a browser that is expecting to talk plain-old HTTP (just boring ordinary text) to a server that is talking HTTPS (encrypted, and VERY confusing for your browser).

You want a [300-series Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) issued by your *web server* to send the client to the appropriate https:// URL.  If you are running Apache you can combine this with the `SSLRequireSSL` directive ([Manual Entry](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl)) to ensure that your clients cannot access resources that should be encrypted over unencrypted channels.

Answer (score 5):

HTTP and HTTPS are different application level protocols, so you can't just redirect on a transport level. You should set up Apache or Nginx or something on port 80 to perform a proper HTTP redirect using a `Location` header.

Answer (score 4):

Setup a relatively blank VirtualHost listening on 80, which does nothing but

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule (.*) https://foo.com$1

Answer (score 2):

Going from http to https is more then just switching ports.  These are two different protocols and your Hudson/Jenkins installation is looking for https and not http.

I don't know of a way to do what you want without installing something like Apache to listen on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably at an impasse here as http & https are dissimilar enough where a simple port redirect is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265034/jenkins-use-it-with-ssl-https), the problem is that you're trying to run Jenkins on a privileged port (<1024). You're mixing things up with port 80 and 443 in your question here.

Run Jenkins on port 8443 (which is usual for an unprivileged HTTPS port) and use `iptables` to redirect from/to 443 and 8443.

To redirect from `http://` to `https://`, Apache and `mod_rewrite` is a good choice, as others have suggested. Alternatively, any tiny web server should be able to send a redirect (HTTP 301 or 302 status) with a `Location` header.